# Make a timer link to a action

Tags: objective-c, timer

I have the code to make it so a notification pops up when I press a button. I want it so it appears when 10 seconds is up.

I know i need to do this:

```
(NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds invocation:
(NSInvocation *)invocation repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

My action is:

```
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hi]
                                                   delegate:hi
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(actionMethodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

If you replace `actionMethodName` with the true method name.

If you want to use the timer route (which is perfectly valid too) it's easier to use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` than to create an invocation. If you do this, keep a reference to the timer and invalidate it when you're done.

---

Based on the updated question details, using a timer and invalidating it is becoming a more preferable method, cancelling perform selector is doable but it isn't as clear as the timer route. I'll show the code for the perform selector route anyway:

```
- (void)startEverything
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}

- (void)handleButtonTap:(id)sender
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showAlert) object:nil];
}

- (void)showAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hi]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Using timers would have the same method structure, but would require a `@property` to store the timer and instead of `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget...` you would `[self.timer invalidate]; self.timer = nil;`.

Comment: In the button action method (where you would have started the timer).

Comment: Sorry new to coding plus im 13

Comment: Ok, you need 1 method that will be called when the button is tapped, that's the button action method. It does the `performSelector` bit. And another method that does the `UIAlertView` bit (let's call it `- (void)showAlert`). Then replace `actionMethodName` with `showAlert`.

Comment: now its all in one bracket but i get an error "expected identifier or'('

Comment: i want the notification to appear in 10 seconds without the button

Comment: i put that in and nothing happened after 10 seconds. am i supposed to do something in the .h file?

Comment: You called `startEverything` when the countdown should begin?

Comment: Ummm no.. how u do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33497/discussion-between-wain-and-jonathan)

Comment: how would i link it to a button

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` It would look something like this:

```
// Action on button press
- (IBAction)myActionButtonPress:(id)sender {
    // setup the selector to fire in 10 seconds
    [self performSelector:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
}

// the selector to be called
- (void)showAlert {
    // display alert
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                                    message:@"This alert displayed 10 seconds after button press"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

this would activate your action method after 10 seconds.

Comment: where would i put this?

Comment: @jonathan updated code so you can see it in a larger context.

Comment: Am i supposed to do something in the .h file?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(IBAction)btnDoneClick:(id)sender {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(buttonactionalert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void) buttonactionalert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hi]
                                               delegate:hi
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: didnt do anything after 10 seconds

Comment: Ok am i supposed to do womething in the .h file?